# OpenWrt Bash shell for loop recognize slash

Tags: bash, shell, openwrt

Bash in OpenWrt, under `/etc` i have a file foreign.txt, with the content as below:
1.0.0.0/24​

When i use ``` for i in ``cat /etc/foreign.txt``; do ipset add redir $i;done ```,the / is treated as', shows '24 numerror.

But when i try ``` for i in ``cat /etc/foreign.txt``; do echo $i;done ``` it shows the correct /.

How can the shell treat it correctly in the ipset command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple special characters after `/24` in your question. See output of this command:

```
wget -qO - 'http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36fdcac2-c6a6-4dd8-aad4-75af2d16827e/view-source' | cat -v
```

---

I suggest to use:

```
tr -cd '0-9./\n' </etc/foreign.txt | while read -r i; do echo ipset add redir "$i"; done
```

If everything looks okay remove `echo`.

---

This `tr` command removes every character from /etc/foreign.txt but `0` to `9`, dot, slash and newline.